# Two progress bars with same styles(default) look different in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

In my android application, I am using an open source library. This library has an activity which creates a ProgressBar(no style) using below code. Say it progressBar1

```
private void createProgressBar() {
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(-1, -2); // match_parent , wrap_content
    params.addRule(13); //center in parent 
    ProgressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    ProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
    RootLayout.addView(ProgressBar);
    ProgressBar.setVisibility(8); //View.GONE
}
```

I am also creating a progress bar in my app using exact same code above, Say progressBar2.
But the two progress bars look different. I do not know what's the reason.
I want both the progress bars to look same.

I also tried changing the progressBar2 by adding it in xml and using from there using below code:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate= "true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Using it in java as:

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Still the progressBar2 looks the same and both progressBar1 and progressBar2 look different... do not know why?

Comment: Please use static variables instead of hard coded numbers. LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem .The library i was using in my application was creating a player activity . That activity is added in my application's AndroidManifest.xml file . There i have not mentioned the theme as android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

After specifying this in the AndroidManifest.xml file for the player activity both progress bars look same .